# How can I get my wordpress to have responsive text

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make my text responsive on my wordpress theme but I'm having problems with the media query

I've looked all over and nothing has been able to help

https://ibb.co/w6bSdJ9

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 680px) {
 h2.h2 { 
 font-size: 12px;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Diego, I'd suggest reading the Stack Overflow article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also copy-paste your properly formatted code here - don't use images to display source code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) 
 {
.heading-text h2 { 
 font-size: 12px;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please add explanation around your code. So that OP and future reader can easily understand your answer.